# Old values in hash map being overwritten by new values?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have one hash map. I'm storing 12 different key,values pairs in it.

The first 8 values are stored fine, but when I try to put the 9th value it overwrites the old value. But the size increases.

If I try to get the old values, I get `null`s. I have also checked the hash map table. Only 8 values are there. The old values are overwritten.
here have only 7 values but size is 9 . how it's possible ?
What could I be doing wrong?[image]

Comment: please provide some code, it will make your question clear, and will allow better answers

Comment: maybe because you´re using the same key?

Comment: Are you adding custom pojos? Is hash and equals properly implemented?

Comment: That screenshot is not very helpful. Please give us some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the size=9 but only 7 values in the table, you are misunderstanding the internal workings of the `HashMap`. All values are not stored in the top-level table. The table is more like "buckets" that store entries grouped by certain hashcode ranges. Each "bucket" holds a chain of linked entries so what you are seeing in the table are just the first entries in each particular range chain. The `size` is always correct though, in terms of total number of entries in the map.

As for entries overwriting eachother, that happens only when you put en entry with a key that is identical (hashCode and equals) to en existing entry. So you are either adding with an existing key, or you are adding with `null` as key (null is permissible as key, but you can only have one entry with the key null).

Check your code, are you adding with `null` keys? If you are using instances of a custom class (one you created yourself) as key, have you implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()` according to the specifications (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)? Are you making sure that you are really using unique keys for all 12 put operations?

Comment: And are you really sure, that you have correctly implemented the hashcode and equals methods? If it were so, it would work correctly, so i assume, somewhere is a mistake. Please post your sourcecode.

Comment: @Selva : If you are doing put() 12 times on your HashMap, and you only have 9 entries in the map after that, then you are not using unique keys. Bear in mind the definition of unique in this context: hashCode() are not the same for the objects and equals() yields false. Either you have at least 4 keys that are equal, or you have incorrectly implemented hashCode() and equals() (if you are using a custom object as key). Post your code and we can help.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use different keys. If that's the case, make sure equals and hashcode for your key class work as required, i.e. when two objects are equal, their hashcodes must be  same. And of course, equals for different key values (or what you'd expect to be distinct keys) must return false.

If that doesn't help, post a minimal, yet complete (compilable) example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: i mentioned the screen shot above,, pls tell me how it's possible?